# What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the roots of the equation $z^{2}+az+b$, and $0$, to be the vertices of an equilateral triangle?

Tags: complex-numbers, problem-solving

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the roots of the equation $z^{2}+az+b$, and $0$, to be the vertices of an equilateral triangle?

Comment: Where's your attempt?

Comment: Found the distance between the two roots, and equated this to the distance between the root and the orign... but it fails

Comment: Why distance between root and origin?

Comment: the origin is a vertice

Comment: Oh yeah, whoops. OK, so how did you get the distance between the two roots?

Comment: if z is in the form of a complex number then the root is the y axis... then find distance between those complex numbers

Answer (score 3):

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be the two solutions. Then we want $b=z_1z_2\ne0$ and
$${z_1\over z_2}\in\{e^{i\pi/3},e^{-i\pi/3}\}=\left\{{1\over2}+i{\sqrt{3}\over2},{1\over2}-i{\sqrt{3}\over2}\right\}\ .$$
This means that ${z_1\over z_2}$ should be a solution of the equation  $t^2-t+1=0$. This implies
$$z_1^2-z_1z_2+z_2^2=0\ ,$$
and therefore
$$(z_1+z_2)^2=3z_1z_2\ .$$
It follows that $$a^2=3b\ne0$$ is a necessary condition for $\triangle(0,z_1,z_2)$ to be equilateral, and as the argument can be reversed, this condition is also sufficient.

Comment: How did you get to the first bit?